# Sending Teams chat message to person/channel from java service

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, azure-bot-service, microsoft-graph-teams

I need to send a Teams message to user/channel from the java service. These are notifications about events that happen in the application (e.g. when someone sells a product, they should receive a message on the teams that the product has been sold). I have already configured Microsoft Graph API for my application in Azure but as far as I know it is not possible to send message directly to users using "Application" permissions. ([DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http))

Is it any walk around for this restriction? Can I use a newly created account specifically for my purposes to authorize from the Java service in graph API and then sending messages to users?

I also found information about bots and sending proactive notifications to users. Is it possible to use it in my case as a proxy between java app and Teams user?

If I have multiple customers from multiple Microsoft organizations and I want to provide them my bot with proactive notification feature How should I deploy it? Does each client have to provide me an access to the Microsoft AD with application permissions and add my bot to his Bot Service? Or it is possible to deploy the bot only in my environment and make it available to my clients somehow?

Comment: This is certainly possible using the Azure Bot Service, though it's easier if you're sending messages to an existing conversation with a conversation ID. I believe you need a bot anyway because bots are the only way for a Teams app to send messages. Are you planning to message users that already have a conversation with the app, or are you planning to message users that have installed the app but aren't in a conversation with it, or are you planning to message users that haven't even installed the app?

Comment: I`m planning to message users that belong to my organization in Teams but they aren't in the conversation yet. I want to start the conversation using the bot and then continue if there is some new notification for the user.

Comment: I created simple bot and deployed it to the Azure but I have one question:
If I have multiple customers from multiple Microsoft organizations and I want to provide them my bot with proactive notification feature How should I deploy it? Does each client have to provide me an access to the Microsoft AD with application permissions and add my bot to his Bot Service? Or it is possible to deploy the bot only in my environment and make it available to my clients somehow?

Comment: That's not one question, that's three questions. Are you trying to get those questions answered, or do you want the questions from your original post answered?

Comment: Sorry for delay. You have right. I think I already have an answer for my question from original post - I have to use bot service to send Teams messages to particular users. So could you please answer the question from my last comment? I will update a question to comply with the rules.

Comment: Yes try the approach what updated by Kyle and see if it fits your scenario, as the application permission is not supported at this point. Being said that, if you want Microsoft to consider implementing the feature then upvote the related [Microsoft Uservoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/41166340-add-support-for-application-permission-to-send-mes) as well.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable? (Since there are multiple other people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called proactive messaging and you can read about it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages

You can deploy your bot wherever you like so long as you make sure the Teams app is published. You can make your bot available to everyone by publishing to the Teams app store, also called AppSource: https://learn.microsoft.com/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/appsource/publish

If you don't want the app to be available to everyone, there may be a way to publish it to individual app catalogs: https://learn.microsoft.com/MicrosoftTeams/manage-apps

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to easily send a message to a channel, but not to a direct message to a person though. To achiever so you can follow the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet)
In other words you can add/setup an incoming web hook to a channel, grab the link provided by it and use a CURL request to send a message like so:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"text\": \"test\"}" https://uri-provided_by_hook
```

Hopefully, there is no need to inform about how to execute an http request through Java code.